# Swift - Stop speech recognition on no talk [iOS 10]

Tags: ios, swift, speech-recognition, sirikit

I am working on an app that uses the new Speech framework in ios 10 to do some speech-to-text stuff. What is the best way of stopping the recognition when the user stops talking?

```
private func startRecording() {
    isRecording = true
    if let recognitionTask = recognitionTask {
        recognitionTask.cancel()
        self.recognitionTask = nil
    }

    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord, mode: AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement)
        try audioSession.setActive(true, with: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
    } catch {
        print("audioSession properties weren't set because of an error.")
        return
    }

    recognitionRequest = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()

    guard let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode else {
        fatalError("Audio engine has no input node")
    }

    guard let recognitionRequest = recognitionRequest else {
        fatalError("Unable to create an SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest object")
    }

    recognitionRequest.shouldReportPartialResults = true

    recognitionTask = speechRecognizer.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest, resultHandler: { (result, error) in

        if let result = result {
            if error != nil || result.isFinal {
                self.audioEngine.stop()
                inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
                self.recognitionRequest = nil
                self.recognitionTask = nil
                let questionText = result.bestTranscription.formattedString                    
                isRecording = false
                self.audioEngine.stop()
                recognitionRequest.endAudio()
                self.audioEngine.inputNode?.removeTap(onBus: 0)

            }       
        }  
    })

    let recordingFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
    inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer, when: AVAudioTime) in
        self.recognitionRequest?.append(buffer)
    }

    audioEngine.prepare()

    try! audioEngine.start()
}
```

I want this code to be called once user does not talk

```
private func stopRecording() {
    isRecording = false
    audioEngine.stop()
    recognitionRequest?.endAudio()
    audioEngine.inputNode?.removeTap(onBus: 0)

}
```

Comment: with out code how can help

Comment: Please try to provide us with some of your code so we can help in this specific case rather than providing an opinion based answer on the overall best way to do this.

Comment: I have updated the post @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: I have updated the post @JoshKopen